# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "fdiary_fdiary" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "fdiary_fdiary"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

i did everything used python manage.py migrate, etc. But when i click on my model in django admin panel it shows this error.
ProgrammingError at /admin/fdiary/fdiary/

relation "fdiary_fdiary" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "fdiary_fdiary"
                                          ^

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/fdiary/fdiary/
Django Version:     3.0.4
Exception Type:     ProgrammingError
Exception Value:

relation "fdiary_fdiary" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "fdiary_fdiary"
                                          ^

Exception Location:     J:\Program Files\Python3.8\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute, line 86
Python Executable:  J:\Program Files\Python3.8\python.exe
Python Version:     3.8.2
Python Path:

['C:\Users\Dell\diary\diary',
 'J:\Program Files\Python3.8\python38.zip',
 'J:\Program Files\Python3.8\DLLs',
 'J:\Program Files\Python3.8\lib',
 'J:\Program Files\Python3.8',
 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages',
 'J:\Program Files\Python3.8\lib\site-packages']

Server time:    Fri, 3 Apr 2020 20:15:51 +0530
Meta:-

```
        ALLUSERSPROFILE     

    'C:\\ProgramData'

    APPDATA     

    'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Roaming'

    COLORTERM   

    'truecolor'

    COMMONPROGRAMFILES  

    'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'

    COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)     

    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'

    COMMONPROGRAMW6432  

    'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'

    COMPUTERNAME    

    'DESKTOP-S6NQ606'

    COMSPEC     

    'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe'

    CONTENT_LENGTH  

    ''

    CONTENT_TYPE    

    'text/plain'

    CSRF_COOKIE     

    'mNHRnYHHB1kzOdnahlwlppBHiLEKYeO0ghFTgshaQGSXzzbS6aU5TI1rnpkWa9vT'

    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  

    'diary.settings'

    DRIVERDATA  

    'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData'

    GATEWAY_INTERFACE   

    'CGI/1.1'

    HOMEDRIVE   

    'C:'

    HOMEPATH    

    '\\Users\\Dell'

    HTTP_ACCEPT     

    'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'

    HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    

    'gzip, deflate'

    HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    

    'en-US,en;q=0.5'

    HTTP_CONNECTION     

    'keep-alive'

    HTTP_COOKIE     

    ('csrftoken=mNHRnYHHB1kzOdnahlwlppBHiLEKYeO0ghFTgshaQGSXzzbS6aU5TI1rnpkWa9vT; '
     'sessionid=amcqamjjcw9chtndh5nzib8nfdv8n1yy; '
     'PGADMIN_INT_KEY=fc56bb57-0d57-4b35-8b29-282be1e4197b; '
     'pga4_session=d8dcf70d-50e4-4474-9aef-6e057e2a6216!P0ZEZvLq08QDIa+4HpmE8XSwdWE=; '
     'PGADMIN_LANGUAGE=en')

    HTTP_DNT    

    '1'

    HTTP_HOST   

    '127.0.0.1:8000'

    HTTP_REFERER    

    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/'

    HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  

    '1'

    HTTP_USER_AGENT     

    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'

    LANG    

    'en_GB.UTF-8'

    LOCALAPPDATA    

    'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local'

    LOGONSERVER     

    '\\\\DESKTOP-S6NQ606'

    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS    

    '4'

    ONEDRIVE    

    'C:\\Users\\Dell\\OneDrive'

    ONEDRIVECONSUMER    

    'C:\\Users\\Dell\\OneDrive'

    OS  

    'Windows_NT'

    PATH    

    ('J:\\Program Files\\Python3.8\\Scripts\\;J:\\Program '
     'Files\\Python3.8\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program '
     'Files\\Microsoft VS '
     'Code\\bin;C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;')

    PATHEXT     

    '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW'

    PATH_INFO   

    '/admin/fdiary/fdiary/'

    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  

    'AMD64'

    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER    

    'Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel'

    PROCESSOR_LEVEL     

    '6'

    PROCESSOR_REVISION  

    '4501'

    PROGRAMDATA     

    'C:\\ProgramData'

    PROGRAMFILES    

    'C:\\Program Files'

    PROGRAMFILES(X86)   

    'C:\\Program Files (x86)'

    PROGRAMW6432    

    'C:\\Program Files'

    PROMPT  

    '$P$G'

    PSMODULEPATH    

    ('C:\\Program '
     'Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules')

    PUBLIC  

    'C:\\Users\\Public'

    QUERY_STRING    

    ''

    REMOTE_ADDR     

    '127.0.0.1'

    REMOTE_HOST     

    ''

    REQUEST_METHOD  

    'GET'

    RUN_MAIN    

    'true'

    SCRIPT_NAME     

    ''

    SERVER_NAME     

    'DESKTOP-S6NQ606'

    SERVER_PORT     

    '8000'

    SERVER_PROTOCOL     

    'HTTP/1.1'

    SERVER_SOFTWARE     

    'WSGIServer/0.2'

    SESSIONNAME     

    'Console'

    SYNAPROGDIR     

    'Synaptics\\SynTP'

    SYSTEMDRIVE     

    'C:'

    SYSTEMROOT  

    'C:\\Windows'

    TEMP    

    'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'

    TERM_PROGRAM    

    'vscode'

    TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION    

    '1.43.2'

    TMP     

    'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'

    USERDOMAIN  

    'DESKTOP-S6NQ606'

    USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE   

    'DESKTOP-S6NQ606'

    USERNAME    

    'Dell'

    USERPROFILE     

    'C:\\Users\\Dell'

    WINDIR  

    'C:\\Windows'

    wsgi.errors     

    <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>

    wsgi.file_wrapper   

    ''

    wsgi.input  

    <django.core.handlers.wsgi.LimitedStream object at 0x00000277CC377700>

    wsgi.multiprocess   

    False

    wsgi.multithread    

    True

    wsgi.run_once   

    False

    wsgi.url_scheme     

    'http'

    wsgi.version    

    (1, 0)
```

setting.py:-
    ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES

```
{}

ADMINS  

[]

ALLOWED_HOSTS   

['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.2']

APPEND_SLASH    

True

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS     

['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    

'********************'

AUTH_USER_MODEL     

'auth.User'

BASE_DIR    

'C:\\Users\\Dell\\diary\\diary'

CACHES  

{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  

'default'

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX     

'********************'

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    

600

CSRF_COOKIE_AGE     

31449600

CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  

None

CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    

False

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    

'csrftoken'

CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    

'/'

CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE    

'Lax'

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  

False

CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   

'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'

CSRF_HEADER_NAME    

'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    

[]

CSRF_USE_SESSIONS   

False

DATABASES   

{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
             'HOST': 'localhost',
             'NAME': 'Fdiary',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': 'postgres'}}

DATABASE_ROUTERS    

[]

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE     

2621440

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS   

1000

DATETIME_FORMAT     

'N j, Y, P'

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  

['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y']

DATE_FORMAT     

'N j, Y'

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  

['%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y']

DEBUG   

True

DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  

False

DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   

'.'

DEFAULT_CHARSET     

'utf-8'

DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   

'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    

'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  

'webmaster@localhost'

DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    

''

DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  

''

DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  

[]

EMAIL_BACKEND   

'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST  

'localhost'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD     

'********************'

EMAIL_HOST_USER     

''

EMAIL_PORT  

25

EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  

None

EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   

'********************'

EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    

'[Django] '

EMAIL_TIMEOUT   

None

EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME     

False

EMAIL_USE_SSL   

False

EMAIL_USE_TLS   

False

FILE_CHARSET    

'utf-8'

FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   

None

FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    

['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']

FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE     

2621440

FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS     

420

FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    

None

FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   

0

FIXTURE_DIRS    

[]

FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   

None

FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  

None

FORM_RENDERER   

'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'

IGNORABLE_404_URLS  

[]

INSTALLED_APPS  

['fdiary.apps.FdiaryConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']

INTERNAL_IPS    

[]

LANGUAGES   

[('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('hy', 'Armenian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kab', 'Kabyle'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('uz', 'Uzbek'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]

LANGUAGES_BIDI  

['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']

LANGUAGE_CODE   

'en-us'

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE     

None

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  

None

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    

False

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    

'django_language'

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    

'/'

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SAMESITE    

None

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SECURE  

False

LOCALE_PATHS    

[]

LOGGING     

{}

LOGGING_CONFIG  

'logging.config.dictConfig'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  

'/accounts/profile/'

LOGIN_URL   

'/accounts/login/'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL     

None

MANAGERS    

[]

MEDIA_ROOT  

''

MEDIA_URL   

''

MESSAGE_STORAGE     

'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'

MIDDLEWARE  

['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django_currentuser.middleware.ThreadLocalUserMiddleware']

MIGRATION_MODULES   

{}

MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    

'F j'

NUMBER_GROUPING     

0

PASSWORD_HASHERS    

'********************'

PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS     

'********************'

PREPEND_WWW     

False

ROOT_URLCONF    

'diary.urls'

SECRET_KEY  

'********************'

SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   

False

SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF     

True

SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  

False

SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD     

False

SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS     

0

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER     

None

SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  

[]

SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY  

None

SECURE_SSL_HOST     

None

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT     

False

SERVER_EMAIL    

'root@localhost'

SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS     

'default'

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  

1209600

SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   

None

SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY     

True

SESSION_COOKIE_NAME     

'sessionid'

SESSION_COOKIE_PATH     

'/'

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE     

'Lax'

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   

False

SESSION_ENGINE  

'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE     

False

SESSION_FILE_PATH   

None

SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  

False

SESSION_SERIALIZER  

'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'

SETTINGS_MODULE     

'diary.settings'

SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   

'm/d/Y P'

SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   

'm/d/Y'

SIGNING_BACKEND     

'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'

SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  

[]

STATICFILES_DIRS    

['C:\\Users\\Dell\\diary\\diary\\static']

STATICFILES_FINDERS     

['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']

STATICFILES_STORAGE     

'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_ROOT     

'C:\\Users\\Dell\\diary\\diary\\assets'

STATIC_URL  

'/static/'

TEMPLATES   

[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': ['C:\\Users\\Dell\\diary\\diary\\templates'],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]

TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    

[]

TEST_RUNNER     

'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'

THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  

','

TIME_FORMAT     

'P'

TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  

['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']

TIME_ZONE   

'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N    

True

USE_L10N    

True

USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  

False

USE_TZ  

True

USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    

False

USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT    

False

WSGI_APPLICATION    

'diary.wsgi.application'

X_FRAME_OPTIONS     

'DENY'

YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   

'F Y'
```

Comment: Before you run migrate, you need to do makemigrations.

Comment: first i used >>>python manage.py migrate then >>>python manage.py makemigrations then >>>python manage.py migrate

Comment: Go to fdiary migrations files to see whether a migration file has been created with your new model in it

Comment: yes new migration file is created